# Abrir foto, com informações sem precisar de clicar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sou iniciante no Jquery, e estou tentando entender um codigo, e um template que baixei para estudo, mais não estou entendendo uma coisa, tem uma janela modal que abre o texto com informações da imagem.

O modal abre, e tem um botão que clico para exibir as informações da foto,

abaixo segue o trecho do codigo que exibe e esconde as informações, sera que tem alguma forma de ao abrir o modal, as informações ja apareçam na foto sem precisar de clicar no botão **modal__info** ?

```
    $modalInfo = $('.modal__info'),


    function showProjectInfo($element) {
    var projectIsOpen = false,
        inProcess = false;

    //off/set handler on modal info btn



    $modalInfo
        .off('click')

        .one('click', function () {
            //find & clone project info to modal window
            $element.next().clone().appendTo($modalContent);
        })
        .on('click', function () {

            if (inProcess) return;

            inProcess = true;

            //already opened - close it
            if (projectIsOpen) {
                $modalContent
                    .find('.project-modal__inner')
                    .smoothAnimate({
                        opacity: [1, 0]
                    }, {
                        duration: 600,
                        complete: function () {
                            $modalContent
                                .find('.project-modal')
                                .smoothAnimate({

                                    height: ['100%', 0]
                                }, {
                                    duration: 600,
                                    easing: 'ease',
                                    complete: function () {
                                        projectIsOpen = false;
                                        inProcess = false;
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                    });
                return;
            }

            //not opened - open it
            //find project info in modal & animate it
            $modalContent
                .find('.project-modal')
                .css('display', 'block')
                .smoothAnimate({
                    height: [0, '100%']
                }, {
                    duration: 10,
                    easing: 'ease',
                    complete: function (elems) {
                        elems
                            .find('.project-modal__inner')
                            .smoothAnimate({
                                opacity: [0, 1]
                            }, {
                                duration: 10,
                                complete: function () {
                                    projectIsOpen = true;
                                    inProcess = false;
                                }
                            });
                    }
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: Como você está abrindo esse modal? Já tentou, após abrir a modal, clicar o botão programaticamente? Algo como `$('#idDoBotao').click()`? Geralmente códigos que abrem modal, tem um evento que é executado após abrir o modal, só por o código de click do botão lá.

Comment: Então, o botão com a classe ( .modal__info ) ja abre a informação, mais eu não queria ter que clicar, tipo, apos eu clicar na imagem passasse 1 segundo e as informações aparecessem, mais não sei como fazer isto!

Comment: Então copia o código q colocar as informações da imagem e põe dentro de um setTimout pra executar 1 segundo depois de abrir a modal. A ideia de clicar no botão via código é pra reaproveitar o código sem ter de copiar.